# Pyvmomi 6.5 and LACP

Tags: python, python-2.7, vcenter, pyvmomi

I'm unable to create a Distributed vSwitch(DVS) with LACP support using pyvmomi 6.5 on vCenter 6.5.  If I create the DVS manually using vCenter, it automatically has LACP support.  However, when using jsut pyvmomi it doesn't have LACP support.  There are python examples of creating the LAG, but that's only useful after LACP support is there.   I'm sensing this might be a bug with Pyvmomi.

Comment: I know, this is unsupported documentation but you can find LACP in Pyvmomi - https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi/blob/master/docs/vim/dvs/VmwareDistributedVirtualSwitch/LacpGroupConfig.rst

Comment: Dont use this API reference, it's deprecated: https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi/tree/master/docs